# Using PlotGraph command from JupyterViz in MyBinder

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, visualization, gap, cayley-graphs

I am executing a program "Newprogram.gap" in GAP file in My Binder. There, I have an output which is an adjacency matrix, $A$ corresponding to a Cayley graph.

1). I need to add the command "PlotGraph(A);" to my program, so that when I input the necessary parameters to "Newprogram(arg);", an output which shows the plot will be generated in the GAP-Jupyter notebook.

Is there a way to do this? (Like, is there a command like Display(PlotGraph(A)); which enables me to plot it by running the program?)

When I first obtained the output of the adjacency matrix in the notebook, as "A1:=Newprogram(arg);" and then typed "PlotGraph(A1);" in the notebook, it was successfult and a plot was generated. But I would like to include the command to the program and execute it so that the output will be the graph.

2). Also, if there is another matrix or a list of coordinate pairs representing edges, which corresponds to a  subgraph of the above graph, is there a way to plot the subgraph also on top of the same graph, marking the edges in a different colour?

I was able to load the packages like "JupyterViz" successfully, by typing "LoadPackage("PackageManager");" at the beginning of the notebook.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am sure we will be able to help, but there is a number of things that are unclear. Do you have a GitHub repository that you have connected to BInder, to have a look? Do you actually have a more general question of drawing a Cayley graph of a group in a GAP Jupyter notebook, and willing to find the best way of doing that, not necessarily with JupyterViz? GAP got several visualisation frameworks with the advent of its Jupyter kernel.

Comment: Also, I don't understand (1): if `PlotGraph(A1)` works and displays the graph, what would you expect from `Display(PlotGraph(A))`? Could you please try to edit the question to make it more clear? for (2), is it just asking how to use different colours for edges?

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with JupyterViz. However, I know that you can use the [Digraphs package](https://digraphs.github.io/Digraphs) to obtain some basic visualisation of directed and undirected graphs in GAP, including from within a Jupyter notebook. These are suitable for graphs on a small number of vertices.

The documentation of these features is given in
[Chapter 9, Section 1 of the Digraphs manual](https://digraphs.github.io/Digraphs/doc/chap9.html#X7CF67F8278D9469C).
The Digraphs package give a visualisation as a string in the [`dot` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)), which can be rendered via the `Splash` command – although within a Jupyter notebook, the command `JupyterSplashDot` from the `JupyterKernel` package must be used instead of `Splash`.

There are many ways of specifying graphs and digraphs within the Digraphs package, including via a list of adjacencies, via an adjacency matrix, as the Cayley graph of some group, and so on (see [Chapter 3 of the Digraphs manual](https://digraphs.github.io/Digraphs/doc/chap3.html)).

Here is a basic example that might suit your purposes:

```
LoadPackage("digraphs");
adj := [[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]];
D := DigraphByAdjacencyMatrix(adj);
JupyterSplashDot(DotSymmetricDigraph(D));
```

And this is how the output might look in a Jupyter notebook, using GAP's [try-gap-in-jupyter binder](https://github.com/gap-system/try-gap-in-jupyter):
[Link to screenshot of the output in a Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wqah.png).

Moreover, in Digraphs v1.4.0 (the newest version, which is newer than the version available in that binder), it is possible to give colours to vertices and edges in these visualisations. For example:

```
OutNeighbours(D);
edge_colours := [["red", "black"], ["red", "black"], ["black", "red"], ["black", "red"]];;
Splash(DotSymmetricEdgeColoredDigraph(D, edge_colours));
```

gives the following output on my local machine:
[Link to screenshot of the output of a graph visualisation with coloured edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICEwq.png).